# When working with a copy of a user in firebase $$conf is added to the object so I can't copy the user to a new location?

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

Unless I am accessing a firebase user in an auth callback, the object has $$conf added to it which prevents me from creating a copy of a user profile to move to a new location. Is there any way around that?

```
//any variation of this doesn't seem to work except for in an auth callback
var teamRef = new Firebase('https://demo.firebaseio.com/teams/' + teamName);
var teamList = $firebase(teamRef.child('profiles'));
teamList.$set(user.uid, user);
```

The user object logs out to this:

```
e {$$conf: Object, $id: "simplelogin:107", $priority: null, email: "andrey@dsrp.tv", md5_hash: "7130dfaebedd9ac16f5e5d73822b160c"…}$$conf: Object$id: "simplelogin:107"$priority: null
```

Even if I just grab the user.uid value I still get the error:

```
   Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($$conf).  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
```

This has stopped me dead in my tracks. I'm currently trying to think of a way to do what I need to do from an auth callback instead of in a different location.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't include any info here about `user` which is the crux of the issue. We can't see how you've copied it or created it.

Answer (score 3):

It would be extremely odd to make a copy of a synchronized object. By definition, either the copy would duplicate all the synchronizing methods, or it would be immediately stale and out of date. More likely, you want to store the user ids in your "teams" path and reference the actual data so that it's always up to date.

That said, to make a copy, just call toJSON to remove the $$ methods. Firebase provides a utility for this:

```
var user = $firebase(...).$asObject();
var userCopy = $firebaseUtils.toJSON(user);
...$set(user.uid, userCopy);
```