# How does toJSON in $firebaseObject work?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I forked a normalization example from [Kato's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/vspo65qm/) and updated it to the current version of AngularFire and Firebase, you can [see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fortuna/c5s4mrhw/3/). I tested around a bit to get a better understanding of how `$firebaseObject` and `$firebaseArray` work and I really get a hang of it.

Except the `toJSON` from `$firebaseObject`.

So I have this little code in the controller:

```
$scope.singlePost = singleMergedPost('post2');
console.log('singlePost', $scope.singlePost);
```

The output normally is:

```
{
  "postData": {
    "bla": "blubb",
    "dateCreated": 1397584465,
    "title": "Another cool website",
    "upvotes": 1,
    "url": "http://www.google.com",
    "user": "simplelogin:2"
  },
  "userData": {
    "email": "kato@firebase.com",
    "jobTitle": "Awesome Dude",
    "name": "Kato Richardson"
  }
}
```

But when I add `toJSON` to `$extend` the output is:

```
{
  "bla": "blubb",
  "dateCreated": 1397584465,
  "title": "Another cool website",
  "upvotes": 1,
  "url": "http://www.google.com",
  "user": "simplelogin:2"
}
```

$scope.singlePost actually contains the same data, but I am wondering about:

1. Why is toJSON even called here, although I haven't sent back any data to the server (at least it looks like from my point of view) yet.
2. Why does `<pre ng-bind="singlePost | json"></pre>` only show the `postData` data?

Answer (score 2):

**1. toJSON**

- `.toJSON()` is called to strip the properties and methods of a `$firebaseObject` or `$firebaseArray` that start with `$` or `$$`. It serializes the object to valid JSON data.
- This is done to display the data in the `<pre>` div for debugging, without the $ methods.
- See [this answer from Kato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27303174).

---

**2. Difference in data**

- `<pre ng-bind="singlePost | json"></pre>` only shows the postData because only the `postData` property of `this` (the `$firebaseObject`) is passed to the `.toJSON()` method in the line `$firebaseUtils.toJSON(this.postData);`
- Compared to passing the whole object (including `postData` and `userData` properties) in `console.log('singlePost', $scope.singlePost);`
- If you log `$scope.singlePost.postData`, you should see the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am a bit confused about the first part. The manual stated that toJSON is only called, when data has been sent back to the server. But in my example I'm only retrieving data.

Comment: `toJSON` is simply converting the object "to JSON". Where does the manual state that it's only called when data is sent back to the server? It is certainly useful when you're sending synchronized data to another server because JSON is the general format of communicating data on the web. In this case though, it's just used to make the object "readable" in a debugging output (the `<pre>`). The data isn't going to a server just by calling `toJSON`. It's just changing "formats".

Comment: The properties/methods with keys that start with "$" wouldn't be valid in JSON format, which is why the `toJSON` strips them off.

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebaseobject **toJSON** - If this method exists, it is used by JSON.stringify() to parse the data sent back to the server. The manual says that toJSON will only be used to tell Firebase what data should be saved into the database.

Comment: Yeah so when your data is synced back to the Firebase server, it calls "toJSON" on the object automatically, if the method exists (as far as I understand it). That doesn't mean though that you can't also call it on the front-end. So yes, it's a method that is used by the server to parse the data it gets, but it's also a method that the client can use to do the same thing.